# Check Image view is empty or not?

Tags: android-studio

i want to stop uploading photos,other data if image view is empty. i'm already set the image as source in image view. but if i'm not capturing image using camera it should not upload. how to do that?

Comment: Please provide more context and information.

Comment: <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:id="@+id/resultq"
                        android:src="@drawable/filesup"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                       />       its my image view. i will capturing image and set it in this image view. suppose i'm not capture any image and press the submit.it should show image view is empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this code helps:

`if (yourImageView.getDrawable()==null){
//your code for stopping uploading here!
}`

Good luck!

Comment: No it's uploading. because in xml file i'm setting android:src="@drawable/image". i need this image for image view. but i dont want upload if there is no captured image. thank you for your answer.

Comment: OK, can you please post some of your code and xml for clarification? because I am not sure about what you need; is it a code to check if imageView is empty or a code to stop uploading or something else?

Comment: Hi @RaghavendraBN, now I understand. 

if (yourImageView.getDrawable()==null) won't work because your imageView is not null because you put @drawable/filesup in it. So, instead of checking if null, check if it contains @drawable/filesup,

The code:

if (imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1).getConstantState()) {//your code for stopping uploading here!
}

Cheers!